# vb.net Resolution same size on two machine but look different

Tags: vb.net, resolution

Ok so i created several programs now... they are all programmed on a 800x600 Resolution

My issue is that if i run the program on the EXACT same resolution on a win 8 tablet or any win 7 or 8 laptop the program jsut doesnt look like what i have on my development machine.

Can anyone explain why this is ? - i looked into DPI but there all set to 100% and seemed to not affect the program at all.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Both Computers SidebySide]
[image: This is the Surface Tablet]
[image: Developers Machine]

Comment: Can you get screen shots to show?

Comment: Does the size of those screens differ ? Are they set to "fullscreen" / "stretch" mode despite being working at a resolution which is lower than their native one ? That would distort images.

Comment: There is your images what gets me even more so is that In the application the width and size are 1150, 899 from what i thought that should fit on a 1200x900 + resolution ( if that resolution existed as default setting )

Comment: Is this a WinForm ui or WPF ?

Comment: This is a WinForm , NOT WPF

Comment: 100% doesn't sound like a dpi setting to me.  What is the dpi settings on each machine/device?

Comment: 100% atm ... any other ideas here ?

Comment: screenshots would go a long way in a question like this

Comment: there above ?? ... actual screenshots.. yeah guess gimmi some time

Comment: sorry imgur.com is blocked at work so your post looked empty.

Comment: Please document your images and indicate clearly what it is that looks wrong, and should be different.  I cannot find any meaningful differences by looking at the first picture you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the size of your desktop icons it looks like you have your text/icons set to 150% of normal size. This affects some applications as well. Since your window is only 600px enlarged by 150% puts it at 900px. This looks about right judging from your screenshot (almost hitting the bottom of a 1080px height)

Check out this article on Microsoft.com:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/make-the-text-on-your-screen-larger-or-smaller

You can also modify your window `AutoScaleMode` property to `False` or `Dpi` (It's not clear what look you want, try playing with all four values of the property.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, resolution is measured by the number of dots in a horizontal or vertical inch. In this sense, the resolution tells us how clearly we can see the image. However when manufacturers talk about a display "resolution", they are using it to mean pixel "dimensions", the number of pixels in each dimension.

Two devices could both have a 800x600 "resolution" in the manufacturer's sense. Namely the displays have 800 pixels across and 600 pixels down. But if the displays are different size, the resolution can be vastly different.

Also if two displays have different total pixel dimensions, a 800x600 image will take up different screen space.

The reason that one display is showing the full image on half the screen and the other does not even show the full image is because the two displays do not have the same number of pixel "demensions". They do not have the same number of total pixels across and down the display.

Comment: ok, is there any reason why say .. teamviewer or any other program ran on either machine , look the same ( size to screen proportion wise ) , but my application is rediculously larger on a smaller screen? - there has to be a way to fix that..

Comment: When you say "they are all programmed on a 800x600 Resolution",  what did you specifically set to specify this resolution?

Answer (score 0):

The differences look like they're due to different visual effects or themes. Check to make sure your themes are set the same, and that all your visual effects are the same: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1908-visual-effects-settings-change.html

Comment: Thanks for your response but  after going through it this weekend I don't believe that visual themes are going to be the issue here... its the pure size of the form itself , it takes up half a screen on my computer and on the surface tablet or laptop on the same resolution takes up more then the entire screen allows.....